# Copying influx data to new measurement with a different tag key value

Tags: influxdb

I am using Telegraf to import sensor data into InfluxDB OSS v1.8 and visualizing them in Grafana. Data are stored in an "mqtt_consumer" measurement with a tag key "topic" and tag key values "**ID-1**/rx", "**ID-2**/rx" etc. Unfortunately the third party platform changed the mqtt topic names so now the same data from the same sensors reach influx with different SensorIDs, let's name them "**ID-A**/rx" "**ID-B**/rx" etc.

Since modifying tag key values of historical data is not allowed in InfluxDB, I would like to make a new measurement where I will copy the historical data with the new tag key value so that data with the old IDs and data with the new IDs will be under the same tag.

Is there a way to do this with influx commands? Should I export data, modify them and import them again (which sounds crazily inefficient)?

Any suggestions, code examples, best practices?